# Ternary allowed to call an explicit copy constructor implicitly?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-bug

Consider the code below:

```
#include <cstdio>
struct A
{
    A(){}
    explicit A(const A&) {std::puts("copy");}
};

int main() 
{
    A a;
    true ? a : A();
    return 0;
}
```

As I understand the ternary would try to copy **a** and should fail since the copy constructor is explicit, however gcc compiles this just fine and creates a copy. Clang spits out an error as expected.

Is this a bug in gcc?

I'm using gcc 8.1 and clang 7.0, in c++17 mode, but I also tried all versions of gcc in [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/) in c++98 mode, and they all behave the same.

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/ncDrBG) is a godbolt link with that code. (You can get one by clicking the "Share" button.)

Comment: Clang reject it whereas gcc accept it [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59e58446807e1411).

Comment: Why would the ternary copy the argument? The result of the expression is discarded. Evaluation of a ternary operator may in general cause the conversion of either argument to a common type, but here that common type is `A` so no conversion is needed.

Comment: @MSalters - Discarded or not, it has to be well formed. The result of the expression is an rvalue, which means an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on `a` must be possible.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Not necessarily disagreeing with you there (i'd have to check Standardese), but those conversions do not occur in all circumstances IIRC. You've got `sizeof(true?a:A())` for instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clang is right to reject it, and it is indeed a GCC bug. I'll quote n4659 (closest document I have to to the C++17 standard) for simplicity.

First and foremost, the type of of the conditional expression in your example, as specified by [[expr.cond] ¶6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.cond#6) must be a prvalue of type `A`.

Now, according to [[expr.cond] ¶7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.cond#7), emphasis mine:

> **Lvalue-to-rvalue**, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer standard
>   conversions are performed on the second and third operands.

`a` must be able to undergo the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. Which for `a` is specified in [[conv.lval] ¶3.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.lval#3.2) (again, emphasis mine) as

> Otherwise, if T has a class type, the conversion **copy-initializes** the
>   result object from the glvalue.

Copy initialization of an `A` from an `A`, in any context, should pick a converting constructor in overload resolution ([[over.match.copy] ¶1.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.copy#1.1)):

> The converting constructors of T are candidate functions.

And an explicit copy constructor is not a converting constructor ([[class.conv.ctor] ¶3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.conv.ctor#3))

> A **non-explicit** copy/move constructor ([class.copy]) is a converting constructor.

A conforming C++ implementation cannot accept the conditional expression your wrote as well-formed.